# Sorting an Acumatica data view on a string field, but using binary collation

Tags: sorting, acumatica, collation, acumatica-kb

I have overridden the APPrintChecks data view to sort by Vendor Code. But since the client's VendorCodes are all numeric, they would like to see the checks sorted so that, for example,  VendorCode '357' is printed before VendorCode '10021'. 
Any ideas on how I can accomplish that?

```
public class APPrintChecks_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPrintChecks>
    {
//change sort from Vendor Name to Vendor Code    
        [PXFilterable]
        public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<APPayment, PrintChecksFilter,
          InnerJoin<Vendor, On<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<APPayment.vendorID>>>,
          Where<boolTrue, Equal<boolTrue>>,
          OrderBy<Asc<Vendor.acctCD, Asc<APPayment.refNbr>>>> APPaymentList;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried soring it by BAccountID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion in the comments, I would first check if there is another numeric/date field you can sort on such as BAccountId or CreatedDate. If this will not do, you will need to find a more creative way to fix it such as:

- Changing Vendor Code Numbering Sequence to include leading zeros,
  example: 0000357, 001021
- Adding a custom field (which is stored in the database) and setting this custom field in the graph to include the leading zeros. Example
  add field UsrVendorCode of type string where you add the leading
  zeros in an event (of the Vendor Graph) such as RowPersisting.
- Adding a calculated database field to add leading zeros and adding this as a custom field (extension of Vendor) in Acumatica (not sure
  whether this is fully supported by Acumatica since it requires
  modifications in DB)